# ¿Sumar valores de un combobox solo si son diferentes MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que tengo un formulario en MS Visual basic sobre actividades que se deben hacer, hay un combobox para cada actividad con valores de 1 a 8, dependiendo de lo que se seleccione en cada combobox se debe sumar a una variable cierto valor, que en este caso es valoresca, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando las actividades tengan el mismo valor en el combobox la variable tome el valor una sola ves, y no se sume las 7 veces, solo que se sume cuando cada actividad tenga valores diferentes seleccionados en el combobox. Ejemplo: Si en todos los combobox esta seleccionado el valor 6, entonces el valoresca es = 2951000 pero si en 6 de los combobox esta seleccionado el valor 6 y en el ultimo combobox selecionaron el valor 7 entonces el valor de la variable seria la suma de los dos valores, valoresca=2951000+2214000(Valor al seleccionar 7 en combobox). Anteriormente el ejercicio lo estaba haciendo con un solo combobox para todas las actividades y con este mismo hacer el calculo, usando este codigo :

Codigo:

```
'Declaramos  condicion multiple de seleccion
        Select Case comboescalafon.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                valoresca = 15493000


            Case 1
                valoresca = 12542000


            Case 2
                valoresca = 9591000

            Case 3

                valoresca = 7378000

            Case 4
                valoresca = 5902000


            Case 5
                valoresca = 4427000

            Case 6
                valoresca = 2951000


            Case 7
                valoresca = 2214000

            Case 8
                valoresca = 1476000
      End Select
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este seria el ejemplo, en la mayoría de actividades seleccione el valor 6 en los combobox por lo tanto el valor esca es 2951000, pero en la actividad informe seleccione el combobox 7 por lo tanto valor esca seria 2214000, entonces lo que quiero hacer es que si uno es diferente como en este caso, que todos son 6 y el ultimo es 7 entonces valoresca tendria que ser 2951000+2214000, este calculo se hace al presionar el boton cotizacion.

Comment: Podes poner un ejemplo? porque la verdad no se entiende. Como que si tienen el mismo valor no sumen y si tienen distintos si? a que te referis exactamente?

Comment: Ejemplo: Si en todos los combobox esta seleccionado el valor 6, entonces el valoresca es = 2951000 pero si en 6 de los combobox esta seleccionado el valor 6 y en el ultimo combobox selecionaron el valor 7 entonces el valor de la variable seria  la suma de los dos valores, valoresca=2951000+2214000(Valor al seleccionar 7 en combobox)

Comment: Kevin usa el boton [edit], pon todo eso en la pregunta, porque es lo mas importante y no lo explicaste. Agrega un par de ejemplos y veremos de poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tambian aclara en que momente calculas ese valor (porque solo agregaste codigo de un case que no hace otra cosa que dar un valor, pero no se ve si recorres los combos o que estas haciendo). Se claro con tu pregunta, nosotros no tenemos toda tu informacion adelante. Mira [ask] si no lo hiciste

Comment: Listo agregue imagen del ejemplo, el calculo se hace al momento de dar click al boton generar cotizacion

Comment: Veo que hay varias preguntas sobre lo mismo en el sitio. Aunque es algo muy bueno que esten estudiando, estudiar implica tratar de aprender por uno mismo, y preguntar sobre un problema puntual, no sobre el ejercicio completo. Seria bueno que trataran por si mismos, y luego vengan con un problema bien particular.

Comment: revisen https://tutorialspoint.com :D

Answer (score 1):

Como no pusiste ninguna clase de restriccion entonces lo mejor seria aprovecharse de las herramientas propias del lenguaje.

Usemos un Dictionary, con clave y valor de los que corresponden con el combo seleccionado.

Vamos a hacer una funcion, que dado el valor del combo devuelva el numero que queres, para eso reaprovechamos tu select. y despues, vamos a recorrer los combos uno por uno, pasarselo a la funcion que devuelve el valor, y tratar de meterlo en el diccionario, siempre, que se ocupe el de ver colisiones.

Al final de todo, recorremos el diccionario y sumamos los valores que hayamos insertado.

Antes del codigo, es esto demasiado? no, porque nos estamos aprovechando de las herramientas del lenguaje en estructuras muy pequeñas.

```
Sub Main()
    'array de valores, simula los combos
    Dim valores(7) As Int32
    valores(0) = 6
    valores(1) = 6
    valores(2) = 6
    valores(3) = 6
    valores(4) = 6
    valores(5) = 6
    valores(6) = 7
    'creo el diccionario
    Dim diccionario As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
    Dim vTemp As Int32
    'Ahora recorro el vector de valores 
    For i = 0 To 6
        vTemp = DevolverValores(valores(i))
        'ahora lo agrego al diccionario
        'me fijo si existe, si no existe lo agrego
        If Not diccionario.ContainsKey(vTemp) Then
            diccionario.Add(vTemp, vTemp)
        End If
    Next
    'Ahora recorro el diccionario y sumo los valores que tengan. 
    'rehuso vTemp como el total de la suma
    vTemp = 0

    For Each pair In diccionario
        vTemp = vTemp + pair.Value
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(vTemp)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Function DevolverValores(valor As Integer) As Integer
    Select Case valor
        Case 0
            DevolverValores = 15493000
        Case 1
            DevolverValores = 12542000
        Case 2
            DevolverValores = 9591000
        Case 3
            DevolverValores = 7378000
        Case 4
            DevolverValores = 5902000
        Case 5
            DevolverValores = 4427000
        Case 6
            DevolverValores = 2951000
        Case 7
            DevolverValores = 2214000
        Case 8
            DevolverValores = 1476000
        Case Else
            DevolverValores = 0
    End Select
End Function
```